# Showing a list of DataTables on DataGrids

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very simple scenario but poor experience in this area and googling around didn't help much.

Consider a classic ASPX page with C# code behind. Let's say I have a list of `DataTable`s (or a `DataSet` with several tables). I need the means to display all tables using one `DataGrid` per table.

I tried binding entire `DataSet` to `DataGrid` but it displayed only the first table.

Something tells me I should be using a `Repeater` in conjunction with `DataGrid` but I need help with this or a totally different (better) alternative.

Comment: another approach could be using dynamic controls

Comment: What about tabbed interface ? Like sheets of excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is an example using dynamic controls:

**ASPX**

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel" Width="100%">
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="Just post" runat="server" />
```

**Code behind**

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s1 = Builder<Product>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build();
        var s2 = Builder<Order>.CreateListOfSize(9).Build();

        var g1 = new DataGrid { Width = new Unit("50%"), DataSource = s1 };
        var g2 = new DataGrid { Width = new Unit("50%"), DataSource = s2 };

        this.myPanel.Controls.Add(g1);
        this.myPanel.Controls.Add(g2);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBind();
    }
```

**Output:**

Note that the view state of each grid is kept among post backs

[image]

Comment: Damn, I knew it had to be silly simple. Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables.aspx

If you are using a Dataset you can do something like:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0]
MyGrid2.DataSource = dataset.Tables[1]
```

Then repeat for each table index within the grid e.g 1, 2, 3

Comment: The .Tables property of a Dataset is a collection of tables in the result, right? I'm not sure the code example will always bind to table[1]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to show in all the tables, even if you will show all the tables how will you manage the heading of every table record. I think you need to first think what you want?

If you have every table same number of columns then its easy to maintain, do you know how to use union?

```
select x, y,z from table1
union 
select x, y,z from table2
union 
select x, y,z from table3
union 
select x, y,z from table4
```

it will create just a single table result from all the four table and can be easily bind.

I don't know you need this or not but I tried to help you anyway :)